# Extracting substrings in R (regular expression)

Tags: r, regex

I have following strings:

```
"Richard H. Hoffman (60-100)" "Alex S. Simmon (72-333)" "Michael S. Pip (1-0)"
```

How do I use regular expression to extract only names from the string?
So the results should look like:

```
"Richard H. Hoffman" "Alex S. Simmon" "Michael S. Pip"
```

Thank you

Comment: [learn regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by `(` and other characters (`.*`), replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\s*\\(.*", "", str1)
#[1] "Richard H. Hoffman" "Alex S. Simmon"     "Michael S. Pip"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Richard H. Hoffman (60-100)", "Alex S. Simmon (72-333)",
             "Michael S. Pip (1-0)")
```

Comment: There is a trigger happy downvoting problem on the site.

Comment: There is rep-ladies-of-the-night problem on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
gsub("^([^()]+).*", "\\1", your_vector)
```

This captures anything *neither* `(` nor `)` into group 1 and replaces the string with the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/LwGWPd/2).